# adding content using .html() method:-- but lost the clicked content ie"this"

Tags: jquery

I want to copy a content from one div when clicked and write it to other div:

But when doing this I lost the clicked content from first div:

```
$(img).click(function(){
  var newdiv=this;
  $(".second").html(newdiv);
});
```

I have two divs with class first and second. First div having images.

Why did I lose the first div's content or the click element, ie "this"?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
$(".first").click(function(){

var newdiv=$(this).html();

$(".second").html(newdiv);

})
```

Edit (thanks [gnarf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91914/gnarf)!)

Comment: `$(this).html()` not `this.html()`

Comment: If you want to copy the "outer" html (i.e. the selected element is a `<img>` which wont return anything for .html():  `var html = $("<div/>").append($(this).clone()).html();` to get the "outerHTML"

Comment: From the text of his question I guessed that he want this all to happen with the ".first" div was clicked; hence, the `$(img)` I considered a mistype.  If he wants this to happen when an <img> tag *within* the div is clicked, then he'd have to do it a little differently, yes.  Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @Patrick - nod - was just giving an example of getting "outer" html - this question is a pretty hard one to understand :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to put any `.first img` inside of `.second` when it is clicked on:

```
$('.first img').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.second').empty().append($this.clone());
});
```